# A question on NoA

Tags: examination

I received the NoA last month. On one hand it says that the Patent is allowed, and on the the other hand I read this line:

**THIS NOTICE OF ALLOWABILITY IS NOT A GRANT OF PATENT RIGHTS**

Once I get a patent granted, do I not have the rights on this ?

Answer (score 1):

You still have to pay the issue fee. After that, the USPTO will grant your patent and publish it formally, at which point you'll have your full patent rights.

Answer (score 1):

This means that before the patent has actually issued it is not a patent. The USPTO preserves a right to withdraw it from issue up until it has actually issued (this can for example happen if there is a change of patent laws that causes a need for reexamination), and also the pending application may become abandoned if you fail to timely submit payment of issue fee, or otherwise fail to be responsive (for example to a notice to correct the application).